# How to decode bellow type of json by dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to decode this Json by Dart but after running it shows some error like this

```
(Unhandled 
Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
    {username: ["The username has already been taken." ...
     ^
{
    "username": [
        "The username has already been taken."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
    ],
    "phone": [
        "The phone has already been taken."
    ],
    "error": [
        "true"
    ]
}
```

Below I am attaching my code to decode JSON.

```
var p = await createAccount(Url.Main_Url+'register');
    var object=json.decode(p);



Future<String> createAccount(String url) async {
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {
      'username': Username,
      'password': Password,
      'name': Name,
      'email': Email,
      'phone': Phone,
      'password_confirmation': Com_Password,
    });
    return json.decode(response.body).toString();
  }
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks beforehands.

Comment: When you wrote "'this json", did you mean that json, which is known only to you and telepaths?

Comment: That error is actually saying, that the **json** in response isn't a correct one. **username** should be surrounded by quotes, but in the error message it is not. Could you please post the real json data the server is outputting?

Comment: Why don't you give an example of this JSON code as text? I mean `response.body` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future createAccount(String url) async {
final response = await http.post(url, body: {
  'username': Username,
  'password': Password,
  'name': Name,
  'email': Email,
  'phone': Phone,
  'password_confirmation': Com_Password,
});
return json.decode(response.body);}


   var p = await createAccount(Url.Main_Url+'register');

    Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = p;

    if(jsonResponse.containsKey('error')) {
      if (jsonResponse.containsKey('username')) {
        Show_Snackbar(p['username'][0]);
      }
      else if (jsonResponse.containsKey('email')) {
        Show_Snackbar(p['email'][0]);
      }
      else if (jsonResponse.containsKey('phone')) {
        Show_Snackbar(p['phone'][0]);
      }
    }
```